# Existing JSON no found, sometimes

Tags: python, json, file, filenotfoundexception

I have a python program that opens a JSON called pos.json inside a folder called autoGen, i try to open it but sometimes it randomly stops working for 10-20 minutes throwing FileNotFound exception, just to start working again randomly, the route is alright I don't understand what is happening

```
currentGen = json.loads(open('./autoGen/pos.json', 'r').read())
# works when it wants to
```

Comment: Something else must be removing and recreating the file periodically.

Comment: I don't think so, the folder have the Json and a program that creates the Json randomly when is executed, the project it's a Conway's life game, that program is not executed by the main program

Comment: Computers don't just randomly get errors like this. If it says FileNotFound, it means the file was deleted.

Comment: Nothing in your Q indicates any way how this could fail. Sorry, there's simply nothing to work with. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: So either figure out why the file disappears and fix that, or use `try/except` in your script to ignore the error.

Comment: It doesn't disappears but doesn't open either, i'm confused too, the file is there and the route is alright, i don't understand neither